Accidently Glued PVC to threaded PVC and it Leaks
I am very new and I accidently glued an elbow to a threaded piece of PVC.  Yes, I know that was dumb, lets move past that :)  Its leaking.  Any idea what I can do to stop the leak?  It has to be an in-place fix.
I should mention it is on a drain for the shower so it isn't under pressure and only leaks when the shower is running.
More Info: The leak is in the cellar.  (It is NOT a basement. The floor is one step up from dirt.)  I will always be able to see if it starts leaking again.
What options are available aside from taking it out?

Please use the [edit] link underneath your post if you want to update it with new information. Thanks and welcome to the site!

What's the difference between fixing it now properly and fixing it later properly? Or are you saying you're willing to keep patching it for eternity?
If it is the latter, then just put a bucket there and empty it once in a while. When you get tired of that, fix it.

better change all the pvc out for that pex..youre gonna have to sooner or later

It is usually better to cut out that section and redo with couplings/other fittings as needed.  PVC glue is more of a solvent and welds the pieces together.
Any patch work fix will most likely be temporary and will start leaking again after you have finished the floor/ceiling.  The leak might not be seen for some time causing extra damage(mold/rot).
There are a few things that can be placed to seal the joint, but no telling if they work for 6 weeks or 6 years.  They are good to stop a leak till you can get to a store.
